# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DayOfWeek' and 'System.DayOfWeek' in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Today using reflector i found this line:

```
 return date.AddDays((double) ((((dayOfWeek < date.DayOfWeek) ? (DayOfWeek.Saturday | DayOfWeek.Monday) : DayOfWeek.Sunday) + dayOfWeek) - date.DayOfWeek));
```

But compiler is throwing error:

**Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DayOfWeek' and 'System.DayOfWeek'**

Any idea.

What is wrong?

Comment: Let me put it this way: What would you expect to be the result of `Tuesday + Friday`? Or `(Saturday or Monday) - Wednesday + Thursday`?

Comment: You say "using reflector"... what were you reflecting?  (Interesting that none of the answers have noticed that this code is presumably generated by a tool...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.DayOfWeek` is an `enum` so `operator +` is not defined for them. You can cast them to `int` type to make it work.

For reference:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a78e9101-eb84-426b-8bdf-63d9b3bdbece

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong here, just there is no any overload operator `+` for [DayfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.dayofweek.aspx).

Yes `enum`, at the end is a *numeric type*, but you need to cast to *concrete numeric type*, before be able to execute math operations.

Answer (score 0):

You must Convert "DayOfWeek.Sunday" to Number First. like (Int32)DayOfWeek.Sunday etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add days until it's the day you want.

See the following example:

```
while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    date= date.AddDays(1);
}
```

The `date` will be incremented until it's Monday.